# How to Update RecyclerView(contains contact list) after add new contact?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contacts

My problem is:

**I have 4 classes:**

- MainActivity.java
- RecyclerViewAdapter.java
- ContactFragment.java
- NewContactActivity.java

**Now is my story:**

- From `MainActivity` I click on `AddButton` to go to `NewContactActivity`
- In `NewContactActivity` I type info contact and click on `SaveButton` to save info to `ContactList` and comeback to MainActivity
- In MainActivity, now RecyclerView is updated with new data that I just added

My files:
**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT=1000;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private SearchView sv;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initializing vars
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        sv = (SearchView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.searchview);
        fab =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        ImageView img_voice_search = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.ic_voice);

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        //Set to toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //Remove Title of Toolbar

        //Add Fragment here
        adapter.addFragment(new CallFragment(),"GẦN ĐÂY");
        adapter.addFragment(new ContactFragment(), "DANH BẠ");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Custom tablayout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHintTextLight), getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextLight));


        //Speech to Text
        img_voice_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Auto focus to searchview when click image voice
                sv.setIconified(false);
                sv.requestFocus();
                speak();
            }
        });

        //fab on click event
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewContactActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            }
        });
    }


    public void speak(){
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL
                , RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        mIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hi speak something");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(mIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //receive and handle it
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT:{
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
                    //get text array from voice intent
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    //set to search view
                    sv.setQuery(result.get(0), true);
                }
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Đã thêm danh bạ: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java:**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    List<Contact> mData;
    Dialog mDialog;
    private TextView dialog_tvName, dialog_tvPhone, dialog_Fname;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Contact> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_contact, viewGroup, false);
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        //Initializing my dialog
        mDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_contact);
        mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        viewHolder.items_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog_tvName = (TextView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_tvName);
                dialog_tvPhone = (TextView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_tvPhone);
                dialog_Fname = (TextView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Fname);
//                ImageView dialog_contact_img = (ImageView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_img);
                dialog_tvName.setText(mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
                dialog_tvPhone.setText(mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone());
                dialog_Fname.setText(mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getFname());
//                dialog_contact_img.setImageResource(mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhoto());
//                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test Click " + String.valueOf(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mDialog.show();

                //Sự kiện click vào icon gọi để chuyển hướng cuộc gọi đến sđt đc chọn
                ImageView call_button = (ImageView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.call_button);
                ImageView chat_button = (ImageView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.chat_button);
                call_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
//                        Intent i1 = new Intent (mContext, MainActivity.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone())));
                    }
                });
                //click vào icon sms để vào ô chat với sđt đó
                chat_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:"+ mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone())));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
        myViewHolder.tvName.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        myViewHolder.tvFname.setText(mData.get(position).getFname());
//        myViewHolder.img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private LinearLayout items_contact;
        private TextView tvName;
        private TextView tvFname;
        private ImageView img;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            items_contact = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_items_id);
            tvName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvFname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFname);
            img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
        }
    }
}
```

**ContactFragment.java:**

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {

    View v;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Contact> lstContact;
    public ContactFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.contact_recyclerview);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), lstContact);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }
    public void loadContacList(){
        //Accessing to contact list and get info
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            List<String> lstPhoneNumber = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> lstEmail = new ArrayList<>();

            //Phone
            Cursor phoneCursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
                    , null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
                    , new String[]{id}, null);

            while (phoneCursor.moveToNext() && phoneCursor != null){
                String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                lstPhoneNumber.add(phoneNumber);
            }
            phoneCursor.close();

            //Email
            Cursor emailCursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI
                    , null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
                    , new String[]{id}, null);
            while (emailCursor.moveToNext() && emailCursor != null){
                String email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                lstEmail.add(email);
            }
            emailCursor.close();
            lstContact.add(new Contact(id, name, name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                    , lstPhoneNumber.size() == 0 ? "" : lstPhoneNumber.get(0)
                    , lstEmail.size()== 0 ? "" : lstEmail.get(0)));
        }
        cursor.close();
        Collections.sort(lstContact, new CustomComparaterLetterContact());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lstContact = new ArrayList<>();
        loadContacList();
    }
    //Class to Compare lstContact for letters
    private class CustomComparaterLetterContact implements Comparator<Contact> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Contact o1, Contact o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

**NewContactActivity.java:**

```
public class NewContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText edtName;
    private EditText edtPhone;
    private EditText edtEmail;
    private ImageButton btnBack;
    private TextView edtAdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);


        btnBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        edtAdd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edtAdd);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
//        LinearLayout llExtraFields = findViewById(R.id.admin);
//        if (llExtraFields.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
//            llExtraFields.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//        } else {
//            llExtraFields.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }
        edtAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
                edtPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
                edtEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);

                String name = edtName.getText().toString();
                String phone = edtPhone.getText().toString();
                String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();

                ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                        .build());
                if (name != null) {
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                            .withValue(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    name).build());
                }

                if (phone != null) {
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                            newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                            .build());
                }

                if (email != null) {
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, email)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                            .build());
                }

                try {
                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thêm thành công danh bạ: " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thêm thành công danh bạ: " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",name);
                setResult(2,intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I spending 4 days for this, and I can not find out the solution. **Thanks you so much**

Comment: Did it back to `MainActivity`?

Comment: Yes, I click on SaveButton and comeback to MainActivity

Comment: Did it displayed toast?

Comment: Cally notifyDataSetChange() method to update adapter on addition of Contacts.

Comment: but  I display RecyclerView by using ContactList and ContactList get data from ContentResolver

Comment: @JohnJoe Toast is not important, that code just is my test

Comment: @Venky Which is will call that method ? and Where I can put it ?

Comment: @JasonMomoa, the method notifyDataSetChange() will tell recycler to update as new data has been push through list in adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add this code in ContactFragment class and try.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 2:{
                loadContacList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, onActivityResult can not to add in ContactFragment

Comment: why you can not add?

Comment: this method only start by add this `Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewContactActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);` and this only on MainActivity

Comment: No problem. Will you try to add this on contact fragment and check is it calling or not?

Comment: No I just test with Toast and no is happened

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`  it's not show @@, please help me

Answer (score 0):

'after adding new element to your recyclerview add'

```
notifyItemInserted(position);
notifyDatasetChanged();
```

'in your adapter.'

Comment: Can you give me more info ?

Comment: Yeah sure, when you will add a new contact in your recyclerview it will be added into it but it  will not be shown while you refresh your recyclerview. that's why when after adding new number you will call the function notifiItemInserted(); it will refresh your recyclerview. and your new item will be shown as well. Hope you got the point.

Comment: Where I can put 2 this, because I don't know how to refresh RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

You were putting **wrong** parameter inside `setResult` method in `NewContactActivity`, that's why `Toast` in  `MainActivity` is not shown.

Modify your `setResult` as below

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Đã thêm danh bạ: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
  }
```